# Bitbucket fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': No such device or address

Tags: git, bitbucket

If you either get that error or

'fatal: could not read Password for 'https://MYUSERNAME@bitbucket.org': No such device or address'

Solution I found below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- My bitbucket User name : goofy
- My bitbucket Password : weliketoparty

Change your Url to
https://goofy:weliketoparty@bitbucket.org/YOURREPO/YOURREPONAME.git

You normally get that URL on your repo on Bitbucket here
[image]

Hope this helped some one.